Check if the resource exists before using data
I want to check if the resource exists before I run below code. I also want to use output of this code further in the code.
data "azurerm_api_management" "res-data" {
  name                = "res_name"
  resource_group_name = "rg_name"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "apim" {
  name                = "res_name"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = "rg_name"
  publisher_email     = data.azurerm_api_management.res-data.publisher_email
  }


While using standard v2 APIM we are not able to fetch the tenant information as per the error  @Panda

I can read resource data. I only want to check res_name exists before I run data "azurerm_api_management"

There is no direct method to fetch the existing resource using terraform, but alternatively we can use external scripts(powershell) using null resource in terraform @Panda

Could you please help me with an example?


Check if the resource exists before using data module in terraform

There is no in-build feature in terraform to check the existence of resource before using data module in terraform.
In general, data module is used for the resource which is preexisted if the resource doesn't exists this will through an error.
Since the requirement is to check the existence of resource in portal before running the data module, we need external script support using cli to achieve this requirement.
Configuration:
variable "apim_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the API Management resource"
  default     = ""
}

resource "null_resource" "check_apim_existence" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      apim_exists=$(az apim show --name ${var.apim_name} --resource-group vinay-rg --query "name" -o tsv)
      if [ -n "$apim_exists" ]; then
        echo "APIM exists: $apim_exists"
      else
        echo "APIM does not exist"
        exit 1
      fi
    EOT
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }

  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}

data "azurerm_api_management" "res_data" {
  depends_on          = [null_resource.check_apim_existence]  
  name                = var.apim_name
  resource_group_name = "vinay-rg"
}

output "apim_name" {
  value = data.azurerm_api_management.res_data.name
  description = "The name of the API Management resource"
}

Deployment:

with this script we can make sure the existence of resource name mentioned under our RG.
If the resource doesn't exist it will through the error at null resource level mentioning the same as we use depends on in data module.

Refer:
azurerm_api_management | Data Sources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim?view=azure-cli-latest#az-apim-show

just a question would this break the apply when the resource not exist? I want to align this code so that if in future I want to run all the terraform apply from scratch

any part of the terrform configuration fails to execute will definately breaks the command terraform apply. here in  this case the apim input is providing to definate value i.e.,  single input but not as a loop. @Panda

I want to continue running pipeline if the resource is not found if i am running terraform plan or apply for the first time(before the resource is created). Is there any option in terraform that can be used? -- I have updated my exact problem in the question
